How do I code and attach a 2D simple melee attack in Unity?
I tried attaching this directly via Add Behavior onto the animation event, but it didn't work. Then I tried to attach it via an Animation Event and that didn't work either.
    public class SwordAttack : MonoBehaviour
    {


        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(other);
        }
    }

It's supposed to just destroy the enemy on hit. I wanted to add more specific logic like death animations and knockback but that can wait until I understand how to do it.
Do I need to code it into when the actual attack is called in my main player script? I thought I could do I the way I tried above. Or is my code off?
I tried Googling a lot, but most of the tutorials start with adding a BoxCollider to represent the weapon and they use the OnCollision method instead. I was originally going to do that but I thought I could shortcut it (as in, the attack would only be active when I swung the sword, so I don't need to go to create a hitbox)
I also wanted to be able to write the method so that I could use it for both enemies and players, just that enemies would have 1 health (they just die) but the player would take damage.
So something simple for players like :
public void TakeDamage (int damage)
{
    currentLives--;

        // Check if lives are zero
        if (currentLives <= 0)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
}


well if you want to do something before destorying the other item, you need to tell it what to do, such as plain an animation and destroy x seconds later

what do you mean

Well you have the code that immediately destroys an item. But if you dont want that behaviour then you need to change that to say what you want to do and give it a delay to complete it and destroy it.   If there was a pizza in your fridge (and its one you like cold and its good and youre hungry) would you write put box in bin. Or would you take the pizza out. Likely eat it. Then put box in bin?

You said that you don't need add the hitbox, can you explain what do you mean? i think you still need to add the hitbox (Collider) to the the sword and the damagable object (player/enemy). Because that is the way to detect if the sword colliding/hit the object.
